# Is it possible to visualize the Strongly Connected Components of directed graph in Gephi?

Tags: graph-visualization, gephi, strongly-connected-graph

I want to visualize the strongly connected components of directed graph in Gephi. I can get the no. of SCC in the graph but can't find a way to visualize it. I have used "Force Atlas 2" to layout the graph of nearly 6000 nodes(~20000 edges), but what i get from the visualized graph is just the "out-degree" edges of nodes. Can someone help me how to visualize the strongly connected components either in gephi or by some other means.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Visualize the strongly connected components" can be a few things. Do you mean: 1. Painting the nodes according to the SCC they belong to? 2. Laying them out according to hteir SCC? 3) Labeling the nodes with their SCC number? 4) something else?

Comment: i meant to laying them out according to their SCC and labelling them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but maybe this can help you.
In the statistics panel, execute DBSCAN.
Then get back to the appearence panel and select node size --> ranking --> number of clusters
This "number of clusters" will appear only after "DBSCAN".
In general, many metrics for "ordering" the graphs, appear only after executing the related statistic, which, in my opinion, while confusing initially, is a good approach, since this way, you get a minimum number of possibilities which, you understand what they mean.